# When is a symmetric block Toeplitz matrix invertible?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, matrix-inverse, block-matrices

Let
$$
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_0 & Q_1 & Q_2 & \cdots\\
Q_{-1} & Q_{0} & Q_1 & \cdots\\
Q_{-2} & Q_{-1} & Q_0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
be a block Toeplitz matrix with $Q_n\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ and $Q_{-n} = Q_{n}^{\sf{T}}$, i.e., $Q$ is symmetric. Additionally, let $Q_0$ be positive-definite.

**Questions:**

1. When is a finite such $Q$ invertible?
2. When does the inverse represent a bounded linear operator for infinite $Q$?

Comment: @Derek - $Q_0$ being positive definite (and hence invertible) does not imply that $Q$ is invertible. For example, suppose $Q_0$ is $1 \times 1$ and equal to the scalar $1$, and $Q$ is the $2\times 2$ all-ones matrix. The inequality Q > Q0+Q0+...Q0 is not true in general.